# Authentication context is null,getting error page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Following steps can be used to recreate this.

1. Create a valid login request.
2. Click back in browser
3. Try to login with valid credentials

```java
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-15 17:31:28,787] [6b1c0dfe-00f5-485a-9d33-443a4d4790ca] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache. Requested client: my ip, URI :POST:/commonauth, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 , Referer: https://aisoip-dev2.alseco.kz/authenticationendpoint/login.do?%3Fclient_id=Qlf9xILuytVmWx915VTdqOuyxkoa&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize&forceAuth=false&nonce=9VPTztKjSDA2dSKblCNjqPG4swm8Ah-KO3YHEX708Bg&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faisoip-tst2.alseco.kz%2Fauth&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=vH2oJ7aDTFOj6mJplSaHEECpG1qdR_rq0JrkqSflGPQ%3D&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=4eecaf00-8e55-45d5-94f3-d5e77ae3dba7&relyingParty=Qlf9xILuytVmWx915VTdqOuyxkoa&type=oidc&sp=AISOIP&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL%3BAuthCertificateAuthenticator%3ALOCAL%3ALOCAL&authFailure=true&authFailureMsg=login.fail.message
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-15 17:31:28,794] [6b1c0dfe-00f5-485a-9d33-443a4d4790ca]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Authentication context is null, redirect parameter filtering will not be done for 4eecaf00-8e55-45d5-94f3-d5e77ae3dba7
```

Comment: my wso2Is version is 5.10.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same `sessionDataKey` twice causes return authentication context as null, and you will end up with an error page.
Browser bank button support and using saved links for login page can be used without such error if you follow the [handling browser back button and bookmarked login page](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/customizing-the-authentication-endpoint/#handling-browser-back-button-and-bookmarked-login-page).

What you have to do here is, adding a registry resource that will contain redirect URLs of different service providers that you configure.

1. Navigate to **Main Menu** -> **Registry** -> **Browse** by login into the management console.
2. Add resource under `/_system/config/identity/config` by selecting the method **Create text content** and giving the resource name **relyingPartyRedirectUrls**
3. Navigate into the created **relyingPartyRedirectUrls** resource and add a property.
4. Property name should be the ***Relying party name*** and value should be the ***redirect URL***.

- If you are configuring this for a SAML app: property name -> "Issuer Name" of the app
- If you are configuring this for an Oauth app: property name -> "OAuth Client Key" of the app

Comment: I set "Oauth Client Key",but seems like getting error because of redirect URL. Can you help with identifying my redirect URL? How my app works: 1) frontend request to my localhost:8080/api/login page and my app redirects him to **wso2** **/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=..** page

Comment: redirect URL should be the URL to which the user will be redirected after successful authentication. Check user-portal login, after a successful authentication user will be redirected to https://localhost:9443/user-portal/overview

Comment: Thank you,fixed!